# How to create an angular library that intercepts http requests made from my app

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

I am trying to create an angular library that intercepts http requests from the app it is imported in.
The issue is that the interceptor doesn't work if it is imported from the library but if I move it inside my app it is working.

the interceptor code from my library looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor () {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            return throwError(err);
        }))
    }
}
```

I'm importing the interceptor in my app like this (app.module.ts):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateCompiler, TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { TranslateMessageFormatCompiler } from 'ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SimpleInterceptor } from '@myname/angular-simple-library';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'languages/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      compiler: {
          provide: TranslateCompiler,
          useClass: TranslateMessageFormatCompiler
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SimpleInterceptor, multi: true },
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any ideas of what could go wrong here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a bracket in your providers, like below

```
providers: [
    [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SimpleInterceptor, multi: true }, ]
  ]
```

If the above does not work, you can review how to setup an interceptor in the [Angular HttpClient Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Answer (score 1):

It should work when the interceptor you create in your library is part of a module. This means you need to create a module inside your library project and add your interceptor to it.

Take for example the npm package [`ngx-progressbar`](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar/tree/master/projects/http):

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgProgressInterceptor } from './ng-progress.interceptor';
import { NgProgressHttpConfig, NG_PROGRESS_HTTP_CONFIG } from './ng-progress-http.interface';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: NgProgressInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class NgProgressHttpModule {
  static withConfig(config: NgProgressHttpConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: NgProgressHttpModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: NG_PROGRESS_HTTP_CONFIG, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

If you add your interceptor you can later import your library module into your app module.